# Bootstrap modal automatically adds a margin-right at second opening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a Bootstrap HTML application that using Modal as confirm dialog, and it could be a modal inside another one. For example I open modal, then I click something on that modal, the first one will be hidden, and open another modal.

From Bootstrap 3.3.6, they are supporting to add a margin-right automatically, and hide the vertical scroll bar, however once the second modal is opened, the scroll bar is not disappeared, and if I close and open again these modals several times, the margin-right will be increased from 17px to 17x2px, and 17x3px ...

I don't know how to solve that problem with Bootstrap modal, or any workaround, I'm also thinking about Angular that keep only 1 modal, and change the modal content (including header, body, and footer), and each modal will be introduced in a separated HTML template, and angular will load a particular template for each modal, but I'm not have much experience with these workaround with Angular.

Here is the sample page that I created for my problem, the page had long content, with `Open Modal` button, click to open first modal, then click on `Open Second Modal` to dismiss the first one and open the second one. If you do that several time, you can see that the margin right is increased, and a white line at the right.

http://plnkr.co/edit/iUuWaSvgDcaKQPTp1Yb2?p=preview

Comment: This is one of the way to fix this issue body {  padding-right:0 !important;  }

Comment: @vas: thanks for your suggestion, however at second modal, the scrollbar will be appeared there, it should be hidden as expected by Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You have written data-dismiss and data-target on one click itself, which is not wrong but internally bootstrap modal has an animate function which takes its own time (appx 500ms). So it would be better if you control it through jqyery.

see below code.

```
$("#secondModal").click(function(){
    $("#firstModal").modal('hide');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#secondModal").modal("show");
    },500)
});
```

The modal method is already integrated within the bootstrap.js which you use.
So it will not show your margin which occurs at runtime.

Comment: It's reasonable, but now I have not only 2 modals, I have more and more place that have that kind of logics, so I would like to do in a more standard way

Comment: Create a generalize method for the same like
`$('.commonClassForModal').click(function(){
      var modalTohide=$(this).attr('data-modal-to-hide');
      var modalToShow=$(this).attr('data-modal-to-show');
     $(modalTohide).hide();
setTimeout(function(){
        $(modalToShow).modal("show");
    },500);
});`

In your html just add two attributes data-modal-to-hide and data-modal-to-show with selectors which you want to show and hide just similar to data-target what you write. Hope this resolves your query @KhoiNguyen

Comment: Yes, from this thread I saw timeout solution, and set margin-right are 2 applicable ways, however I would like to find a better solution, that don't need to put a timeout function with a hard number of ms there. Especially, I'm looking for a way that can use AngularJS, only change the content, modal would be kept there

Comment: If you are looking for AngularJS then it would be better if you create a directive which creates your own modal at runtime and whenever any other modal is required remove the previous one from the DOM itself and its efficient too, i have tried it a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily handle using stylesheet according bootstrap modal display once into another bootstrap modal.

```html
    <html>
    <head>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
      <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">Click here</button>

      <div class="modal fade modal-admin" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modelbtn">Click here</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
     <div class="modal fade " id="myModal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id='close' class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click=''>Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#close").click(function(){
            $('.modal-admin').css('width', '500px');
        });
    });
      
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#modelbtn").click(function(){
             $('.modal-admin').css('width', '200px');
             
             $("#myModal1").modal();
             $('#myModal1').css('margin-left', '200px');
                                 
        });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```